# Any clean way to combine find and instanceof in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to find in some Iterable some elements that both conform to some given type, and validates a predicate taking that type as an argument.

I wrote this method using imperative-style programming, which seems to conform to my expectations. Is there some way to write this in a more "scalaesque" way?

```
def findMatch[T](it: Iterable[_], clazz: Class[T], pred: T => Boolean): Option[T] = {
  val itr = it.iterator
  var res: Option[T] = None
  while (res.isEmpty && itr.hasNext) {
    val e = itr.next()
    if (clazz.isInstance(e) && pred(clazz.cast(e))) {
      res = Some(clazz.cast(e))
    }
  }
  res
}
```

Comment: Kotlin have `filterIsInstance<MyClass>()`, which is way more straightforward.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `collect` if you want to `find` and then `map`.

```
scala> val it: Iterable[Any] = List(1,2,3,"4")            
it: Iterable[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> it.view.collect{case s: String => s}.headOption
res1: Option[String] = Some(4)
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `case` statement can of course include a guard so that only elements for which `pred` is `true` are collected.

Comment: In Scala 2.9 the method `collectFirst` was added to `TraversableOnce`. The above code can then be written as `it.collectFirst{case s: String => s}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with an existantial type `X forSome{typeX}` rather than using `_` as type parameter. This then would enable you to write it with the mentioned find method and use the map method on the Option type:

```
def findMatch[T](it: Iterable[X forSome {type X}], clazz: Class[T], pred: T => Boolean): Option[T] = {
    it.find{ e => clazz.isInstance(e) && pred(clazz.cast(e))}.map{clazz.cast(_)}
}
```

Comment: You do not need an existential type here as `Iterable[+A]` is covariant - so you can just use `Iterable[Any]` here.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide your problem into subproblems a more idiomatic version is easy to find.
You want to

1. find all instances of `T` in your `Iterable[Any]`
2. cast them to `T` to make the compiler happy
3. find the first matching element

For the first point you can easily use the `filter` Method on `Iterator`. So you have

```
it.iterator.filter(x => clazz.isInstance(x))
```

which returns you an `Iterator[Any]` that contains only `T`s. Now let's convince the compiler:

```
it.iterator.filter(x => clazz.isInstance(x)).map(x => x.asInstanceOf[T])
```

Okay, now you have an `Iterator[T]` - so you just need to find the first element fulfilling your predicate:

```
def findMatch[T](it: Iterable[Any], clazz: Class[T], pred: T => Boolean): Option[T] = 
  it.iterator.filter(x => clazz.isInstance(x))
             .map(x => x.asInstanceOf[T])
             .find(pred)
```

Comment: -1 for looping through the whole iterable with filter. It is ineffective and does not even terminate for infinite iterables.

Comment: Oh, I see that passing through the iterator make the filter and map operations laziesque.

Comment: @Kim yes, it does not terminate for infinite `Iterable`s that is true. Your statement that it is ineffective is false though as I am calling `filter` on an `Iterator` [which is evaluated lazily](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_RC1/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L382).

Comment: Aah I overlooked the call to iterator. SO doesn't let me take back my vote...wtf?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterable`'s `find` method and pattern matching with a guard:

```
scala> val it: Iterable[Any] = List(1,2,3,"4")
it: Iterable[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> it.find { _ match {
  case s: String if s == "4" => true
  case _ => false
}}.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]
res0: Option[String] = Some(4)
```

For an introduction to pattern matching have a look at:
 http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch03.html

Comment: and use "collect" for finding multiple matches: it collect { _ match { case i:Int if i < 4 => i } }

Comment: Not great, as it returns an `Option[Any]` and not `Option[String]`.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet: One could append a cast: `.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]`

Comment: I came out with `def findMatch[T](it: Iterable[Any], clazz: Class[T], pred: T => Boolean): Option[T] = 
    it find { e: Any => clazz.isInstance(e) && pred(clazz.cast(e))} match {
      case Some(e) => Some(clazz.cast(e))
      case _ => None
  }`

I was however for something less verbose, so as to avoid to define the findMatch method at all. The casts are cumbersome.

Comment: What I actually dislike with the above solution, is that the cast is performed twice: once as a "side effect" of the pattern matching, and a second time to obtain the right output type. I was actually hoping of some clever way to use pattern matching combined with find to have these casts performed naturally.